# Energy eigenvalue with Potential $-e^2/ x$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, potential, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

If I have potential which are very well-known like, square barrier, or square well, or step potential, What I do is to set the boundary conditions in Schrödinger's equations. Sometime, the ground state can be done using variational principles using trial wave function.

Now for example I have a different shape of potential which is 
$$V=
\begin{cases}
-e^2/x & \text{for } x>0 \\
\phantom M \infty & \text{for } x<0
\end{cases}
$$

The potential is more like compared to three dimension hydrogen atom problem where the potential is $-e^2/r$. Do you think it will be any help to find the energy eigenvalue for the given potentials?

**Or, more precisely, my intention is to find the energy eigen value of one dimensional hydrogen atom potential using the known Three dimension.**

Comment: Eigenvalue is one word, not two (same with eigenvector and eigenfunction).

Comment: Is there some relationship between eigenvalues in different numbers of dimensions? There obviously is when the potential is proportional to $r^2$, because this is $x^2+y^2+z^2$, but for $1/r$ the three dimensions do not contribute additively.

Comment: Please describe the 1D charge distribution that gives rise to this potential.

Comment: Consider the Schrodinger problem with $\ell=0$ and $\chi(r)=r\psi(r)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not really clear what you are asking, but the $-e^2/x$ potential  has quite a long history: See, for example  Larry K. Haines, David H. Roberts, "One-Dimensional Hydrogen Atom"
  American Journal of Physics 37, 1145 (1969); https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1975232.

Comment: My intention was to find the energy Eigen value of one dimensional  Hydrogen atom potential using the known Three dimension.

Comment: If I remember there is a route to this via the path integral. I think C R Hagen was an author on the paper.

Comment: My bad. It was *Hagen Kleinert* and Duru who looked at path integral for 3d hydrogen, but I think there was a bit about 1d hydrogen in that paper.

Comment: Here is another reference: "The mapping of the Coulomb problem into the oscillator" 
by David S. Bateman, Clinton Boyd, and Binayak Dutta-Roy, American journal of physics 
60 (1992) pp 833-836